# regex for url without protocol

Tags: regex

I need a regex to check a url with this format: "www.stackoverflow.com".

I do **not** want to allow http or https: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

I've been looking for a good 45 minutes and can't find anything. only regex that allows both or that require "http".

The closest I've seen is "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)$" but this allows anything as long as it includes "."

Acceptable expression: www.example.com

Unacceptable expression: http://www.example.com, example.com etc.

Basically something that makes sure it starts with "www.". If possible I also want to make sure it ends with ".something". And all the other URL regex attributes like not allowing "!" etc.

Comment: #6 here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149, just take off the `(https?:\/\/)?` part.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using ASP.NET c#

Comment: removing (https?:\/\/)? did not work. Nothing gets through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this pattern

```
^(?!https?).*$
```

with `i` modifier for case insensitive.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/197)

---

Per comment below use this pattern

```
^(?!https?)www\..*$
```

or simply

```
^www\..*$
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add so it checks for "www." start as well?